# Advice/guidance on how to turn this add tenant method into a request that can be accepted/rejected

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm building a sample app in Laravel based around tenancies. Landlords can add tenants, but it's not an accept/request system. Once the Landlord clicks add and fills out a form, the tenancy is created.
This is a sample row in the database.

[image]
Database row.
I added the accepted method so a tenant can accept/reject, but it's just sitting there atm, it's not doing anything (yet). How can I allow the 'add' to be a request, and for the landlord to accept or reject it?
This is the profile page. I was thinking of having the logic like this. How hard is it?

```
<div class="container">
    @if($user->userType != "Landlord")
    <div class="row">   
    `//Add Tenancy - I'll start this so only lanlors can see this button`
        `<a href="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/create" class="btn btn-primary">Start Tenancy</a>`

    `//If Tenancy request sent`
    `button to accept or reject.`

`//If if in tenacny`
    `list property address, or landlord name`
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a form around your Add Tenancy button and when the button is clicked the form is submitted and you're redirected where you want to go. This is how the default Laravel Auth example works when logging out.

```
<form method="POST" action="/account/tenancy/{{$user->id}}/create">
  <button type="submit">Add Tenancy</button>
</form>
```

You can handle the request via routers/controller.

### Edit

If you want to control the button based on the status of the tenancy you can pass a `$status` variable to your blade template and use it.

```
@if ( $status == 'can-add' )
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Tenancy</button>
@elseif ( $status == 'accepted' )
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" disabled>Accepted</button>
@elseif ( $status == 'denied' )
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>Denied</button>
@elseif ( $status == 'pending' )
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" disabled>Pending</button>
@else
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled>A Default</button>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I have it done. Is it ok to use booleans to control if the request is sent, accepted or not ect, and display to correct buttons based on what the booleans are?

Comment: @Jayk yeah, that is fine. You could use a string named `$status` and control it based on that. I think using a simple boolean may be tricky. `$status` could be equal to sent, accepted, or whatever you need it to be. I'll update my answer.